# Prime ideals in the same connected component of Spec

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unit. Is it true that two prime ideals $p$ and $q$ are in the same connected component of $\text{Spec} R$ iff there exists a series of minimal primes ideals $p_1,\dots,p_n$ with $p\in \overline{p}_1$, $q\in\overline{p}_n$, $\overline{p}_i\cap\overline{p}_{i+1}\neq \emptyset$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$. (Here $\overline{p}$ denotes the closure of $p$ in $\text{Spec} R$, that is, the set of primes $q$ with $p\subseteq q$.)

Comment: And what did you try to do? Can you prove one of the two directions? Where did you get stuck? And what does it mean $p \in p_1$? It seems that $p$ and $p_1$ are both prime ideals of $R$, is it not the case?

Comment: The condition $p_i\cap p_{i+1}\neq \emptyset$ is empty because the intersection of two ideals is never empty.

Comment: You are right, I meant $V(p_i)\cap V(p_{i+1})\neq \emptyset$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$. Sorry about that. But i think Navigetor23 noted this.

Comment: This is exercise 14(b), page 143, from Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*. Try to look there because Bourbaki gives a hint in part (a) of the exercise.

Comment: @navigetor23 i am the same messi, now i am curious on how to get back to my old account. I came to that conclusion from an example given in fossum's book. I will give exact reference later as i have just made a move and dont have my books handy.

Comment: @navigetor23 Thanks for the reference, i will look at the hint.